# Perfectly rouded border-radius for flexbox items

Tags: css, flexbox, border-radius

I have items like these which are flex-items inside a flexbox container.

My items in normal size:

[image]

My items squeezed:

[image]

My CSS looks like this:

```css
body { 
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  justify-content:space-between;
  width: 100%;
  position:relative;
}

.item {
 display: inline-flex;
 align-items: flex-end;
 justify-content: center;
 flex: 1 0;
 height: 2.4rem;
 border: 1px solid #000;
 border-radius: 0 0 50% 50%; /* Important part */
 padding-bottom: 10px; 
 user-select: none;
 font-size: 0.9rem;
 height: 250px; 
 margin: 0 5px;
}
.info {
  margin-top: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div class='item'>1</div>
  <div class='item'>2</div>
  <div class='item'>3</div>
  <div class='item'>4</div>
  <div class='item'>5</div>
</div>
```

Is there a way to make them look perfectly rounded (RadiusX == RadiusY, not ellipsed) in every size?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Welcome to SO. Can you please add html code to make a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Hello! Please add your HTML so we can show you a specified solution and reconstruct your attempt

Comment: You're using 50% - try using an actual value in `rem`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't assign `50%` to `border-radius`, it'll calculate exactly from the percentage of both width and height(in this situation, `40px`/`80px`). If the width and height are not equal, it will end up an ellipse shape.

Just use an arbitrary big number instead.

You don't need to calculate exactly what the number it is, just make it bigger than the width or height could be(In this example, `500px` is more than enough for `160px` height, *but don't be too crazy about it*):

```css
div {
  width: 80px;
  height: 160px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.fifty-percent {
  border-radius: 0 0 50% 50%;
  background-color: salmon;
}

.big-number {
  border-radius: 0 0 500px 500px;
  background-color: steelblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="fifty-percent">50%</div>
<div class="big-number">500px</div>
```

You can see [this article](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/border-radius/) to see how `border-radius` works and [this article](https://www.codementor.io/tips/1314923785/border-radius-in-percentage-and-pixel-px) to see how exactly `border-radius` is calculated.

Comment: Sadly this won't work because width of my items are not static

Comment: @eckler Just give it a big number that your item will never surpass, even something like `9999px`. It'll automatically become a round shape, but don't go too crazy.

Comment: Thanks! That works just fine. Add this info to your answer please so I could mark it as a decision.

Comment: @eckler Just added this info, hope it helps.